# How to install a specific version/build of Safari?

Tags: macos, safari

A customer has reported a bug in Safari 10.1.1 (11603.2.5) which I cannot reproduce in Safari 10.1.1 (12603.2.4) on macOS Sierra.

Everything is updated in the App Store.

- Is it possible to install a specific build number of Safari?
- If not, what accounts for the different builds on different machines?
- Are there release notes available at the level of build numbers?

Comment: Please ask one question.

Comment: @JashJacob Should I open three separate questions for these closely-related things?

Answer (score 2):

I do not think you can find level of builds for Safari. As long as you are running the current latest version of Sierra, You will have the latest version of Safari.

To find the latest updated version and patch details you can [track them on Apple Support.](https://support.apple.com/en-ae/HT201222)

The last updated for [Safari came on 15 May 2017](https://support.apple.com/en-ae/HT207804) - **Safari 10.1.1**

Supported OSes - *OS X Yosemite 10.10.5, OS X El Capitan 10.11.6, and macOS Sierra 10.12.5*

Answer (score 1):

I frequently had the same issue. I always ask the customer to include the App bundle (his build) with the bug report together with a screen video of the problem (Quicktime) and this works quite nicely in 99% of all cases.

Afaik, there's no other way to get a specific build. If Apple would allow you to do this, is would be great though.

Make sure to run the same version of OSX to reproduce the problem. I have the latest 2 or 3 versions installed in parallel on my Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Each build is for a different OS version, so you cannot install the other build on another OS version.

- Safari 10.1.1 (11603.2.5) is for OS X El Capitan (10.11)
- Safari 10.1.1 (12603.2.4) is for macOS Sierra (10.12)